# android convert utc time in 24 hours format

Tags: android, date, time, utc, type-conversion

In my app i need to convert my current date into UTC format, i can successfully converted, now problem is i need 24 hours format check it out my below code

```
public static String CurrentDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    LogUtil.d("new Date()" + new Date());

    return df.format(new Date());
}
```

now my `CurrentDate` returns 1.45 but i need 13.45 how can i convert utc in 24 hours format?
i have search through google but dint get proper answer, all suggestions are most welcome
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor you're calling? Look carefully at the pattern you're providing, and what that means, vs what you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the hour part at your `SimpleDateFormat` constructor call from `hh` to `HH` does the job:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Output:

```
2015-07-13 13:53:02
```

See also [Table of Date and Time Patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

As Jon Skeet said, check the String you pass on `SimpleDateFormat()` : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

You need to replace "hh" with "HH" so it will become "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
Of course if you only need the hour and minute that should be "HH:mm"